# Memory won't be released until APP enters background

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, memory

I'm working on a app with a side menu, using two ViewController in a ContainController. 
And when after close the side menu ViewController(the deinit method is called), the memory just would not be released(it's about 23 MiB), until the app entered background.
The "Leaks" tool build in Xcode 9 says there's no memory leak at all...
Anyone could tell me what's wrong?
Thanks a lot in advance!

```
import UIKit
import CoreData

enum MenuState {
    case Collapsed 
    case Expanding  
    case Expanded 
}

class ContainerViewController: UIViewController {

    weak var managedObjectContext: NSManagedObjectContext!

    weak var mainViewController: MasterViewController!

    weak var menuViewController: MenuViewController?

    var currentState = MenuState.Collapsed {
        didSet {
            let shouldShowShadow = currentState != .Collapsed
            showShadowForMainViewController(shouldShowShadow: shouldShowShadow)
    }
}

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    mainViewController = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "mainView") as! MasterViewController
    view.addSubview(mainViewController.view)

    DispatchQueue.global(qos: .userInteractive).async {
        self.mainViewController.managedObjectContext = self.managedObjectContext
        self.addChildViewController(self.mainViewController)
        self.mainViewController.didMove(toParentViewController: self)
    }

    let panGestureRecognizer = UIPanGestureRecognizer(target: self, action:#selector(self.handlePanGesture(_:)))
    self.mainViewController.view.addGestureRecognizer(panGestureRecognizer)

    let tapGestureRecognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action:#selector(self.handleTapGesture))
    self.mainViewController.view.addGestureRecognizer(tapGestureRecognizer)
}


@objc func handlePanGesture(_ recognizer: UIPanGestureRecognizer) {

    switch(recognizer.state) {

    case .began:

        let dragFromLeftToRight = (recognizer.velocity(in: view).x > 0)
        if (currentState == .Collapsed && dragFromLeftToRight) {
            currentState = .Expanding
            addMenuViewController()
        }

    case .changed:

        let positionX = recognizer.view!.frame.origin.x + recognizer.translation(in: view).x
        recognizer.view!.frame.origin.x = positionX < 0 ? 0 : positionX

        let boundX = mainViewController.view.frame.width - menuViewExpandedOffset
        if positionX > 0 {
            recognizer.view!.frame.origin.x = positionX > boundX ? boundX : positionX
        }
        recognizer.setTranslation(.zero, in: view)

    case .ended:

        let boundX = mainViewController.view.frame.width - menuViewExpandedOffset
        let hasMovedhanHalfway = (recognizer.view!.frame.origin.x > boundX * 0.3)
        animateMainView(shouldExpand: hasMovedhanHalfway)

    default:
        break
    }
}

@objc func handleTapGesture() {
    if currentState == .Expanded {

        animateMainView(shouldExpand: false)
    }
}

//ADD MENUVC
func addMenuViewController() {
    if (menuViewController == nil) {
        menuViewController = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
            .instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "menuView")
            as? MenuViewController

        view.insertSubview(menuViewController!.view, at: 0)

        addChildViewController(menuViewController!)
        menuViewController!.didMove(toParentViewController: self)
    }
}

let menuViewExpandedOffset: CGFloat = 480


func animateMainView(shouldExpand: Bool) {

    if (shouldExpand) {

        currentState = .Expanded
        animateMainViewXPosition(targetPosition: mainViewController.view.frame.width -
            menuViewExpandedOffset)
    }

    else {
        animateMainViewXPosition(targetPosition: 0) { finished in

            self.currentState = .Collapsed

            self.menuViewController?.view.removeFromSuperview()
            self.menuViewController?.removeFromParentViewController()
            self.menuViewController = nil
        }
    }
}



func animateMainViewXPosition(targetPosition: CGFloat,
                              completion: ((Bool) -> Void)! = nil) {

    UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5, delay: 0, usingSpringWithDamping: 1.0,
                   initialSpringVelocity: 0, options: .curveEaseOut, animations: {
                    self.mainViewController.view.frame.origin.x = targetPosition
    }, completion: completion)
}

func showShadowForMainViewController(shouldShowShadow: Bool) {
    if (shouldShowShadow) {
        mainViewController.cameraBGimage.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.6
        mainViewController.cameraBGimage.layer.shadowOffset = CGSize(width: 0, height: 1)
    } else {
        mainViewController.cameraBGimage.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.0
    }
}


}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Provably there is nothing wrong with your app. The iOS system will manage the memory the way it thinks it is best.

If your objects are deallocated when they should be, then you are fine. If you want to get a better understanding of when your views are deallocated you can always use de `Allocations` tool of the `Instruments` and filter it by your app's name.

Comment: Thanks for your reply!